# Aesthetic problem with JSON line order and indentation when using Powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I am using Powershell to edit a json-file. The indentation in the edited file looks weird and the lines are not in the order I want them to be.

I have used this code to edit my json-file:

```
$appSettings = Get-Content C:\test\appsettings.json | ConvertFrom-Json

$httpData = @{"Url"="http://*:2201"}

$httpsData = @{}
$httpsData.Add("Url","https://*:2203")
$httpsData.Add("SslProtocols",$("Tls12", "Tls13"))
$httpsData.Add("Certificate",@{"Subject"="SubjectName";"Store"="My";"Location"="CurrentUser";"AllowInvalid"="True";})

$endPointsData = @{}
$endPointsData.Add("Http",$httpData)
$endPointsData.Add("HttpsInlineCertStore",$httpsData)

$KestrelData = @{}
$KestrelData.Add("EndPoints",$endPointsData)
$appSettings | Add-Member -Name 'Kestrel' -Value $KestrelData -MemberType NoteProperty

$appSettings | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 6 | Out-File "C:\test\appsettings.json"
```

This is the result I want:

[image: How I want it to look]

This is the result I get:

[image: What it looks like now]

How to fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: You can use my function [Format-Json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56324939/9898643) for this

Comment: newtonsoft.json module?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/56224503/6654942

Comment: Are you sure that’s not just a display issue where your text editor is doing something to auto-indent the json when you open the file? By default powershell (core) will indent json with two spaces per level - as a test, try using ```out-host``` instead of ```out-file``` and see what it looks like when it’s written to the console. Alternatively, try using a different editor or just echoing the file contents to console to bypass any formatting behaviour in your text editor…

Comment: @mclayton Looks like powershell 5.1 has bigger indents.  Doing it with powershell 7 would be a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problems**:

- The **ordering issue** is due to the fact that you are using [hashtables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) (`@{ ... }`), whose entries are inherently *unordered*.

  - **Use *ordered* hashtables** instead (**`[ordered] @{ ... }`**), which preserve *definition order*.
- The **pretty-printing** behavior of [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json) **in *Windows PowerShell* is unfortunate**: 4 spaces per indentation level and 2 spaces between a property name and the (start of) its value, with nested content indented *relative to the position of the opening delimiter (`{` or `[`)*, with the closing delimiter at the same indentation level as the opening one.
  Additionally, even *empty* arrays and objects have *multiline* representations.
  All in all, this makes for a needlessly wide and/or tall representations that make deep hierarchies hard to grasp.

  - **Pretty-printing in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) is now more sensible** and **works the way you want**: 2 spaces per indentation level, 1 space between property name and the (start of) its value, with nested content indented *relative to the start of the enclosing property* and the closing delimiter at the same indentation level as the property itself.
    *Empty* arrays and objects now have *inline* representations (e.g.   `"Foo": []`)
  - Note the neither PowerShell edition offers ways to *customize* pretty-printing (only a way to *disable* it, with `-Compress).

---

**Solutions**:

- Use the **`ConvertTo-AdvancedJson`** cmdlet from the **third-party [`PSAdvancedJsonCmdlet`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSAdvancedJsonCmdlet) module** (install with `Install-Module -Scope CurrentUser PSAdvancedJsonCmdlet`, for instance): it is essentially a backport of the better `ConvertTo-Json` implementation found in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)

  - For the sake of completeness: It follows that migrating to [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) would solve the problem too, but such a migration is certainly not something to undertake casually; on the plus side, PowerShell 7+ has fixed many problems that still plague Windows PowerShell, and continues to gain new features.
- If installing modules isn't an option, and short of writing your own JSON serializer, you can use a **quick-and-dirty, suboptimal *approximation* of the desired pretty-printing**, using a **single, [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based string substitution via the [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator**, as shown in the sample code below.
- Short of writing your own JSON serializer, there is a **string-substitution solution with *stateful, line-by-line* processing**, wrapped in a `Format-Json` custom function in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56324939/45375) - you can use it *instead* of `ConvertTo-Json`, because it has the latter built in.

  - If you also want to use the function *in PowerShell 7+*, use [this tweaked version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71664664/45375), though note that the only good reason to do so would be if you wanted to indent by something *other* than *2 spaces*, via the `-Indentation` parameter.

The following is a **self-contained example** that:

- Uses `[ordered] @{ ... }` hashtables to ensure the desired ordering, via a *single, nested* ordered-hashtable *literal*.
- Is cross-edition-compatible:

  - It detects running in PowerShell 7+, in which case no workaround is needed.
  - In Windows PowerShell, it uses `ConvertTo-AdvancedJson` *if available*, and falls back to the quick-and-dirty, suboptimal, regex-based string-replacement technique.

    - For an explanation of the regex used and the ability to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/xEXZJj/1).

```bash
# Simulate your file input.
# As an aside: it's better to use -Raw with Get-Content in this case:
#    Get-Content -Raw C:\test\appsettings.json | ConvertFrom-Json
$appSettings = [pscustomobject] @{ Foo = 'bar' }

# Construct the data to add.
$KestrelData = [ordered] @{
    'Endpoints' = [ordered] @{
        'Http'                 = [ordered] @{ 'Url' = 'http://*:2201' }
        'HttpsInlineCertStore' = [ordered] @{
            'Url'          = 'https://*:2203'
            'SslProtocols' = 'Tls12', 'Tls13'
            'Certificate'  = [ordered] @{
                'Subject'      = 'SubjectName'
                'Store'        = 'My'
                'Location'     = 'CurrentUser'
                'AllowInvalid' = 'True'
            }
        }
    }
}

# Add the data as a property to the preexisting JSON document.
$appSettings |
    Add-Member -Name 'Kestrel' -Value $KestrelData -MemberType NoteProperty

# Serialize back to JSON (piping to Out-File omitted)
if ($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -ge 7) { 
  # PowerShell (Core) 7+ - no workaround needed.
  $appSettings | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 6
}
elseif ((Get-Command -ErrorAction Ignore ConvertTo-AdvancedJson)) {
  # Windows PowerShell: Use the PSAdvancedJsonCmdlet module, if available
  $appSettings | ConvertTo-AdvancedJson -Depth 6
} else {
  # Windows PowerShell: Imperfect workaround.
  ($appSettings | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 6) -replace '(?m)(?<=^ *) {4}', ' '
}
```

Output with the quick-and-dirty workaround:

```json
{
 "Foo":  "bar",
 "Kestrel":  {
     "Endpoints":  {
           "Http":  {
               "Url":  "http://*:2201"
              },
           "HttpsInlineCertStore":  {
                   "Url":  "https://*:2203",
                   "SslProtocols":  [
                      "Tls12",
                      "Tls13"
                     ],
                   "Certificate":  {
                        "Subject":  "SubjectName",
                        "Store":  "My",
                        "Location":  "CurrentUser",
                        "AllowInvalid":  "True"
                       }
                  }
          }
    }
}
```

Output in PowerShell 7+ or with `ConvertTo-AdvancedJson`:

```json
{
  "Foo": "bar",
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://*:2201"
      },
      "HttpsInlineCertStore": {
        "Url": "https://*:2203",
        "SslProtocols": [
          "Tls12",
          "Tls13"
        ],
        "Certificate": {
          "Subject": "SubjectName",
          "Store": "My",
          "Location": "CurrentUser",
          "AllowInvalid": "True"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: :) :) 
Just wondering about the last line... What is going on here:

-replace '(?m)(?<=^ *) {4}', ' '

??

Comment: @HammerOfSweden, please see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/xEXZJj/1) for an explanation; you can also experiment there. I've added this link to the answer too.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

`($appSettings | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 6).Replace('  ',' ') | Out-File "C:\test\appsettings.json"`